# Adding a requirement in Symfony2.4.2 throws an exception

Tags: symfony, routes

Adding a requirement in Symfony2.4.2 throws an exception.

This code in routing.yml works fine

```
RouteName:
path:  /tms/{fname}/{lname}
defaults: { _controller: MyWorkTMSNewBundle:Testing:show, age:40 }
requirements:
```

But adding a requirement, as below, throws an exception.

```
RouteName:
path:  /tms/{fname}/{lname}
defaults: { _controller: MyWorkTMSNewBundle:Testing:show, age:40 }
requirements:
age:40
```

Am I missing something?

The exception I get is as below

> FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/Resources/config/routing.yml" from "Symfony/app/config\routing.yml". (Unable to parse at line 5 (near "age:40").)

AND

> ParseException: Unable to parse at line 5 (near "age:40").

Answer (score 2):

i think the only problem is the indentation

try it like

```
RouteName:
    path:  /tms/{fname}/{lname}
    defaults: { _controller: MyWorkTMSNewBundle:Testing:show, age:40 }
    requirements:
        age:40
```

Answer (score 0):

The age in `requirements` must be a regular expression, like

```yaml
RouteName:
    path:  /tms/{fname}/{lname}
    defaults: { _controller: MyWorkTMSNewBundle:Testing:show, age:40 }
    requirements:
    age: \d+
```

See: [Adding Requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements) in the Symfony Routing docs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions John and Ferod.

@Ferodss - I knew there is an option with regular expressions, but I was trying with specific numbers.

@John - You were right. The importance of spaces was new to me. Probably this is a YAML constraint.

Adding a few more things that I discovered with my trials.

1. Only strings can be provided as requirements in the way I did. Symfony returned an error when I cleared the cache which says it should be a string.
2. If you are very keen it should be a number, like I was, use double quotes around it :)

   `RouteName:
    path:  /tms/{fname}/{lname}
    defaults: { _controller: MyWorkTMSNewBundle:Testing:show, age:40 }
    requirements:
     age: "40"`